Spring Bean hierarchy of objects based on tenant/region
I have a spring webapp. Here's a simple structure to explain my problem
java/
└── com/
    └── example/
        ├── controller/
        │   └── MyController.java       // REST Controller
        ├── service/
        │   └── MyService.java          // Service interface
        ├── client/
        │   └── EC2Client.java          // EC2Client

MyController injects MyService and MyService injects EC2Client.
There are multiple Beans of EC2Client. These are used as per the region. Region is received through the rest API in controller.
I would like to create bean hierarchy based on regions(us-east, us-west, etc). So for each region, I should have a controller, service, and a ec2client bean.
Ideally if I had to create a single class bean based on region I could create quailifier beans. But how do I do this for the whole heirarchy. I could potentially have 5+ regions So, want to make this dynamic in nature

For any one who stumbles across this, solution was to use Spring Custom Scopes.

link-only answers are not considered the best answers - check [answer]: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, ..."

Let me find some time to edit this.

EC2Client.java can be a interface or abstract class and add some impl class of EC2Client.java by region(EastEC2Client.java\WestEC2Client.java). All of subclass of EC2Client.java can be put in a map when startup. "MyService" injected the map. can choose a region ec2client from the map in the service.
enter image description here

Nice attempt, but this does not scale. Plus my question is more about creating class objects based on region. Like how we have request scopes in Spring. I did add an answer for how to solve the original problem. Do check that out if you're curious
